# How to install the 'pgfplot' package in Lubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, latex

How can I install the `pgfplot` package in Lubuntu?  For information, I use TeXstudio, I searched in it for a while for  a WYSIWYG tool that can manage TeX Packages but didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

The files `amsrefs.sty` and `pcatcode.sty` are not included in the package `texlive-latex-base` so that is probably why you are told that the directory does not exist.

The files you are looking for is found in another TeX Live package, namely `texlive-bibtex-extra`. Install it and your document should compile. To install it do e.g.

`sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra`

Comment: Sorry, but how can this answer my question?